How can I silently listen for user keypresses in the terminal (with modifier keys detection) in Zig?
I’ve been working on a terminal-based application in Zig, and I need to handle user keypresses without echoing them on the terminal. Additionally, I want to detect if any modifier keys (e.g., Ctrl, Alt, Shift) are pressed during the key event.
Here are the specific requirements:

The terminal should not display the keypresses.
The solution should identify the pressed key and the active modifier keys.
It needs to work on multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, macOS).

I’ve searched online and looked through Zig’s standard library, but I couldn’t find a straightforward or built-in way to achieve this. Writing raw system calls feels tricky, especially for handling cross-platform compatibility.
Has anyone tackled a similar problem?
Are there any patterns, libraries, or approaches in Zig you’d recommend for such a use case?
Here’s a simplified example of what I hope to achieve:
User presses `Ctrl+Alt+A`:
- Key: 'A'
- Modifiers: "Ctrl", "Alt"

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance. 
I’ve tried using Zig’s standard input functions, but they don’t allow for silent input handling (where the terminal doesn't echo the pressed keys). I also looked into using system calls for detecting key presses and modifier keys, but didn’t find a clear cross-platform solution that would work out-of-the-box in Zig.
I was expecting to find either a built-in way to handle silent key events with modifier detection, or at least a simple method to accomplish this without diving into complex system calls. However, what I encountered was either incomplete solutions or ones that didn’t meet the cross-platform requirements.

What you receive via Zig's standard input is actually what terminal-based programs receive from the terminal. It's not a Zig thing – terminals in general do not have a general concept of "base key and modifiers" the way graphical environments do; they are fundamentally an ASCII text-oriented interface1. Even special keys are received in-band as text (special "escape sequences"), and the terminal is controlled by writing more such sequences to stdout.
Unix-like systems have a tcsetattr() system call to put the tty (the pipe between terminal app and your program) in raw mode so that it reports character-by-character instead of line-by-line, and the same system call is also used to disable echoing so that all input becomes "quiet". Beyond that, however, there are no system calls for keyboard input from terminal2 – everything is done through ordinary read(stdin) and write(stdout).
The "terminal" protocol grew from its ASCII roots via various vendor extensions (at first largely DEC, then Xterm) and there's no standards group overseeing the protocol (though attempts have been made) so the capabilities vary depending on which terminal app you use. Most terminal apps follow the lead of Xterm (with some of them implementing the "extended keyboard protocol" extension introduced by the Kitty terminal, but that is nowhere near universal yet).
Only Windows was an exception in that its "console" system had actual out-of-band key events in addition to stdio; but of course it relied on non-portable Windows system calls, and nowadays it's deprecated in favor of the terminal-style interface (Windows Terminal has a "Win32 keyboard" protocol similar in concept to the Kitty one).
Generally it is not something you ever want to deal with "by hand", so you'll need an external library such as libtermkey or ncurses or Notcurses if you're writing in C or a language that has C interfaces. Libtermkey and its successor Libtickit will enable the necessary modes and decode the input for you into a more usable abstraction. Some also handle putting the terminal in "whole-screen app" mode if that's what you're writing. I also found a Zig-native zig-spoon library; for Golang you might use the bubbletea package.
Note limitations: Although you will be able to detect some modifiers even without the Kitty extension, there are certain combinations that won't work at all (or only work with some types of keys but not others), and in other cases they will have to be derived back from the text input you receive:

For keys that send ASCII characters, both Shift and Ctrl are pre-applied – which means that A and Shift+A are not sent as the same 'A' key differing in modifiers; they are literally given to your program as a and A characters with the modifier effect already applied. The program needs to guess "Shift+a" from "A".

Similarly Ctrl turns the characters into "ASCII control characters", and does so in a way that Ctrl and Ctrl-Shift are impossible to distinguish. For example, both Ctrl+A and Ctrl+Shift+A send the exact same input (the ASCII control character denoted as ^A or 0x01 – again, not "A with modifiers" but a new character with those modifiers pre-applied).
Notably, this makes it impossible to distinguish Ctrl+M from the Enter key , or Ctrl+I from Tab.

Alt uses a prefix mechanism (the ESC control character aka 0x1B), so both Alt and Alt+Shift produce distinct input sequences.
But it means that "Alt+A" and "Esc followed by A" are only distinguishable via timings; they generate the exact same data otherwise. (Programs often use e.g. a 100 ms timer following the ESC byte to distinguish a lone Esc keypress from a special sequence.)

The combination of Ctrl+Alt involves both mechanisms, so Ctrl+Alt and Ctrl+Shift+Alt aren't distinct. (For example, Ctrl+Alt+A gives you \x1B\x01 – the ESC 0x1B prefix byte followed by the "Ctrl-shifted A" i.e. 0x01 byte – assuming the terminal supports this combination.)
(Some terminals do allow Ctrl+Shift+letters to have distinct keycodes using Xterm's "modifyOtherKeys" extension… which has two incompatible modes, and the terminal program cannot opt into this feature – it has to be enabled in the terminal's settings.)

"Navigation" keys such as Home or PgUp are a different story. They're not text but they're still reported as text-based sequences, like ESC [ A for ↑ Up. Originally the protocol didn't support any modifiers, but most terminal apps implement the Xterm extension that does (except Rxvt which goes its own way).



1 More advanced "terminals" did exist in the past, including those with advanced input/graphics support (even X11 was originally a 'terminal' thing), but those were not what lives today as "terminal emulator" apps. Terminal emulators of today generally emulate the DEC VT220.
2 Of course, there are OS-specific system calls to get raw key events, which is what graphical apps use – it's what the terminal itself uses, as well – but they only work if the app has its own window (input events are strongly tied to window focus; even more so on Wayland), so if you use them, then your app is no longer a "terminal app".
